# While refreshing the page in browser getting 404 in nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-config

Deployed my react app in Vultr and below is my `nginx` configuration. navigating to a page and while refreshing the browser throws 404 error. I have added `try_files $uri /index.html;` under location and did restarted the nginx by running below command. Could someone please advise to fix the issue !

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

But while adding `try_files $uri /index.html;`  I am getting error System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
groupByTags.js:38 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at groupByTags.js:35:39
at c (regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)

// nginx configuration

```
server {
        
                listen 80;
                server_name example.com www.example.com;
                root /var/www/example.com/build;
                index index.html;
        
            location /service {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
               try_files $uri /index.html;    ## try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; ## tried this one
            }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out this. I have added another block of `location / { try_files $uri /index.html; }` in nginx conf file solved the page refresh issue. Second block of `location /service {...` is used for reaching the existing api services.

In my case, my api service end point looks as follows , example: `service/listOfBlogs`. So if your api endpoind starts with `api/some_end_point`, then location block should be written as `location /api {...`

Full nginx conf listed below:

```
server {
        
            listen 80;
            server_name example.com www.example.com;
            root /var/www/example.com/build;
            index index.html;
            
            location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
            }

        
            location /service {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }
        
    }
```